# How to Replace CentOS's GRUB with Ubuntu's GRUB

Tags: grub2

I can't boot into Ubuntu 12.04 just CentOS. How should I do to revert back Ubuntu GRUB?

Comment: Do you have CentOS still installed?  Ubuntu is installed on a separate partition?

Comment: yes, Ubuntu in a separate partition

Comment: This question should get you on the right track:  http://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows  (Here you have centOS instead of Windows).